# I tried to add a Bootstrap dropdown button to <a> but the dropdown menu wont work. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

```
<li><a href="#" class=" dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">CONTACT<span class="caret"></span></a>    
    </li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Can someone please help me. everything in  is from bootstrap's website. Heres the whole html file
http://pastebin.com/YXsVPRhz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `data-target` from the `a.dropdown-toggle`, and an `id` for the targeted `ul`.

For the `a`, add a data-target attribute which is the id of the `ul`:
`data-toggle="dropdown"    //sample name`

For the `ul`, add an id:
`id="dropdown"    //sample name`

so it should be:

```
<li><a href="#" class=" dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown-menu" aria-expanded="true">CONTACT<span class="caret"></span></a>    
    </li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ul` as a sibling of the anchor

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class=" dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">CONTACT<span class="caret"></span></a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5rmhq7v/)